# Counting words in a post

Tags: posts

How can I count words in a post? Something like the one displayed just below the post?

Can someone please show me the code for getting this. I have been searching everywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How hard did you search?  I searched Google for "wordpress count words in post" and found a function for it in the first result!

Put this in `functions.php`:

```
function prefix_wcount(){
    ob_start();
    the_content();
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    return sizeof(explode(" ", $content));
}
```

Then call it in the template like this:

```
<?php echo prefix_wcount(); ?>
```

Comment: Or, better yet (albeit less known) `str_word_count()`

Comment: @m0r7if3r http://php.net/str-word-count has some strange side effects with numbers and hyphens. I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 6):

Just count the spaces and add 1:

```
// No need to count markup.
$text        = trim( strip_tags( get_the_content() ) );
$word_number = substr_count( "$text ", ' ' );
```

Another way, taking the old American double space tradition into account:

```
$word_number = preg_match_all( '~\s+~', "$text ", $m );
```

Comment: I'm not sure if counting spaces is reliable. When I learned to type, it was always two spaces after the period. Long explanation as to why it's fallen out of favor here - http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/why-all-the-hate-two-spaces-after-the-period

Comment: @RayMitchell Americans … :P I have added a second approach.

Comment: @toscho - More like, Old People.

Comment: @toscho - there's rumor that some Brits do it to, but I have a hunch they were taught by expatriates. :)

Comment: Also, french uses a space between the last word in the sentence and exclamation or question marks. So, yeah. Old people. :)

Answer (score 5):

Easy and straightforward approach.

```
$word_count = str_word_count(trim(strip_tags($post->post_content)));
```