# How to count total words for posts published by one author?

Tags: users, count

How can I get a total word count of one author's posts? Thanks.

To be more clear, I wanna show the total word count in the author archive page, preferably using code.

Comment: it's the task of custom coding. whoever might have a time, might post it. otherwise, you can always look for plugins if there exists any.

Comment: Can you help with the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic concept how I'd do the word counting and showing the count. Hopefully this serves as a starting point.

I think it would be a good idea to store the word count in a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), so it isn't calculated on each and every author archive page load.

```
function author_word_count() {
    // get current author
    $author_id = get_queried_object_id();
    // check if there's valid word count transient, show that if so
    $word_count = get_transient( $author_id . '_word_count' );
    if ( $word_count ) {
        echo $word_count;
    } else {
        // fallback to calculating word count, show it and save it as transient
        $word_count = calculate_author_posts_words( $author_id );
        echo $word_count;
    }
}
```

Helper function for calculation

```
function calculate_author_posts_words( $author_id ) {
    $author_posts = get_author_posts( $author_id );
    $count = 0;
     if ( ! empty( $author_posts->posts ) ) {
            // If you have gazillion posts, then this might hit your server hard I guess. 
            // There might be more performant ways to doing this, but I can't think of any right now
            foreach( $author_posts->posts as $p ) {
                $count = $count + prefix_wcount( $p->post_content );
            }
     }
     set_transient( $author_id . '_word_count', $count, $expiration ); // Save the count, set suitable expiration time
    return $count;
}
```

Helper function to get authors posts

```
function get_author_posts( $id ) {
    // Do WP_Query with author's id and return it
}
```

Helper function to count single post's word count. Modified from [Counting words in a post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52456/counting-words-in-a-post)

```
function prefix_wcount( $post_content ){
    return sizeof(explode(" ", $post_content));
}
```

You could also hook a custom update function to [`save_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) to update the word count transient when a new post is made or and existing one is updated.

```
function update_word_count_transient( $post_id ) {
    // check that we're intentionally saving / updating post
    // get post content
    // get transient
    // calculate words and and it to transient count
    // save transient
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_word_count_transient' );
```

This is just a concept and I haven't tested the code examples. Please add prefixes, validation, sanitizing, fix typos/bugs and fine tune functions as needed before using in production.

*If you don't know php and are looking for a copy-and-paste solution, then please hire a professional to do the work for you*

Answer (score 0):

Tools to Manage Your WordPress Word Count

PublishPress is a great WordPress plugin for content, and it has a Content Checklist addon that allows you to choose a maximum and a minimum length of your WordPress content.

Here's how PublishPress and the Content Checklist works ...

- Install the PublishPress plugin.
- Get the Content Checklist addon from PublishPress.com. Download the
  Content Checklist files.
- In your WordPress site, go to "Plugins", then "Add New" and install
  Content Checklist.
- Go to "PublishPress", then "Checklist" in your WordPress admin area.
- Look for the “Number of words” field. Here you can choose a minimum
  and maximum word count:

More ideas at: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-word-count/

Comment: Seems you didn't get my point...

Comment: I don't need the count for a single post, neither to limit the words for a post. Just wanna show the total word count of one author's posts in the author archive page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solutions for this [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52456/counting-words-in-a-post).

Or please use Google to find another way, the keyword can be *"count word of the post wp"* or same it.

Best regards,

Comment: I really did that. "count word of the post wp" will be easy. But to get " total word count of one author's all posts" might be not from Google.

Comment: If so, you must get all post of that author after count word for each the post of the author and sum all results.

Comment: Can you help me with the code to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have free time, please research to do it. Thank you very much ^^